# How to fire an event when making a selection of an editable combobox?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, combobox, selectionchanged

I have a `ComboBox` that is databound to an `ObservableCollection` of `strings`. The `ComboBox` is also editable, so you can either enter in your own value or select one from the list. The issue I'm running into is the index of `SelectedItem` seems to be the index of the last item you selected when you've entered in your own value in the `ComboBox`, though it's -1 when you have `IsTextSearchEnabled` set to true.

The problem is, if someone entered their own value and then decide to instead select the item on the `ComboBox` that had been selected before, the index doesn't change so the `SelectionChange` event doesn't fire. How could I get an event to fire in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this...
I hope this helps:

```
Dim oldSEL As String = ""

'always checking while you move your mouse over the combobox (when altering selection) and using the keyboard to (alter selection)
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.MouseMove, ComboBox1.KeyPress
    Dim currentSEL As String = ComboBox1.SelectedText
    If Not (oldSEL = "" And currentSEL = oldSEL) Then
        fire()
        oldSEL = currentSEL
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub fire()
    Trace.Write("text selected changed")
End Sub
```

You should change all the Combobox1 to your liking.

Comment: This is a good suggestion. I'm not using  this exactly for a few reasons, but you got me thinking about how I could do this. I'm using the MouseLeave event instead. But thanks!

Comment: You could use this idea to make a better code like one using custom events and interfaces. But it's up to you for now coz it's I'm not very familiar with those. haha.